# Doing a count where value equals true on a simple_form input in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have my replies table:

```
class CreateReplies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :replies do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :menu
      t.boolean :rsvp, :default => false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And i then have in my _form.html.erb

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :rsvp, [[true, 'Yes'] ,[false, 'No']], :first, :last %>
```

and in my index.html.erb

```
<%= Reply.where(rsvp:false).count %>
```

I'm very new to Ruby so learning fast, clearly the fact it's not producing any results means i could be way off the mark. I want to be able to have my input with two choices. Attending / not attending.

And then i want to do a count to show values for those attending. Any help would be much much appreciated.

**Update**

Ive still not solved this issue. Running tests in the console give back the wrong values, however a simple .count works fine.  There must be an issue with how im setting the true or false on the actual checkbox.

Comment: Are you having issues with both `_form.html.erb` and `index.html.erb`? Or one of them?

Comment: Well i think it must be something missing from how im going about it. I can't tell which file i might be getting an issue from

Comment: Can you try the same query in Console and see what you get?

Comment: Yeh i tried two ways, both gave me 0: 1.9.3-p327 :002 > Reply.where(rsvp:true).count
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "replies" WHERE "replies"."rsvp" = 't'
 => 0 
1.9.3-p327 :003 > Reply.where(:rsvp => true).count
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "replies" WHERE "replies"."rsvp" = 't'
 => 0

Comment: What does `Reply.all.count` get you?

Comment: `Reply.all.map(&:rsvp)` What does this get you?

Comment: ["attending", "true", "true", "false", "true", "true"]

Comment: Your data and syntax in the console - both seems to be ok. I'm sorry really cannot find what the problem is here.

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
<%= Reply.where(:rsvp => false).count %>
```

See - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html, section 20 "Calculations"

Comment: As a rule we should probably point people towards best practices when giving solutions... I would *not* use `arel` queries in view code.  This should be either in the controller or model.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, i did try this, but im still getting a value of '0' on the count, when there should be 6 on the count

Comment: The syntax used by the OP is correct - It's Ruby 1.9.3 hash syntax. Nothing wrong in that. Agreed with @nzifnab

Comment: Sorry, try Reply.where(:rsvp => "FALSE").count.  And nzifnab is right, you probably want to stick this in a controller, assign the result to an instance variable, and then print the variable in your view.

Comment: Thanks, i will try this. For creating instance variables, would i create a new controller?

Comment: @Mat-visual don't you already have a controller rendering out this view?

Comment: I do indeed, but it's not working as i would expect, i might be doing it wrong though.